# Use either action or actionListener based on a condition in a PF datatable composite component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, composite-component

I am trying to create a datatable composite component, this component needs to be used by two groups of developers, one who are using `Spring web flow` and they need an `action` attribute for the command link inside the composite component datatable and the others need the `actionListener` attribute.

I would like to use the same xhtml for both cases. Is that feasible?

```
  <composite:attribute name="isWebFlow" />
```

Would an attribute like above help me configure? The problem is that I have many command links in the datatable composite component and hence I cannot repeat them / render them based on the condition like :

```
<c:if test="#{cc.attrs.isWebFlow eq 'true'}">  
     <p:commandLink styleClass="filter #{cc.attrs.styleClass}" action="#{cc.attrs.action}"/>
</c:if>    

<c:if test="#{cc.attrs.isWebFlow eq 'false'}">  
    <p:commandLink styleClass="filter #{cc.attrs.styleClass}" actionListener="#{cc.attrs.actionListener}"/>
</c:if>
```

Is there any other way to do this and re use the xhtml? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using rendered attribute:

```
<p:commandLink styleClass="filter #{cc.attrs.styleClass}" action="#{cc.attrs.action}" rendered="#{isWebFlow}"/> <p:commandLink styleClass="filter #{cc.attrs.styleClass}" action="#{cc.attrs.action}" rendered="#{!isWebFlow}"/>
```

Comment: I have many command links like this in the xhtml and I cannot keep repeating the code like this as already mentioned in the question.